# pandas reading csv with large texts fpr nlp

Tags: python, pandas, csv, nlp, jupyter-notebook

I have a large csv file made of 1 column and with a single cell in each row, around 18800 of them. Each cell contains a large text. The file size is big; around 318 Mb. I am using Jupyter notebooks.

I am trying to read the csv file into a pandas dataframe, however I am receiving the following error:

`ParserError: Error tokenizing data. C error: Expected 1 fields in line 12, saw 2`

I tried some tricks, however, I am not getting the original text or even the number of rows. Instead I am getting something like 200 rows.

Comment: It sounds to me like you might need to figure out if you're using the wrong delimiter. i.e., comma, tab, space, etc

Comment: Please share some sample data and your code!

Comment: I am not sure what to use as delimiter as this is one cell per row. each cell contains texts with commas, dots, | numbers etc.

Comment: i am using pd.read_csv("path ")

Comment: when i use jupytor notebooks on Azure it works fine, however, the problem is that Azure only allows me to upload files 10 mb in size and mine is over 300 mb. anyway around this?

Comment: To get an answer to a Jupyter question, it'll get in front of folks who are more likely to be able to help if you ask that specific question and add that tag.

Comment: I was able to solve the matter, the path to the files was wrong. I had to use os to find the go to the correct location. thanks